# Why doesn't the csrf_exempt work on my view in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, django-views

I am making a fetch request to one of the Urls as:

```
function like(id){


fetch(`/likepost/${id}`, {
    method:'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        'id':id
    })
})



.then(response => response.json())
.then(result => {
    console.log(result)
})
```

and the url maps to this view:

```
path('likepost/<int:post_id>', views.likepost,name='like')
```

and the view is defined as:

```
@csrf_exempt
def likepost(request, post_id):
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        id = data.get('id')
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=id)    
        post.likes = post.likes+1
        post.save()
        return JsonResponse({'message':'liked succcessfuly'})
   else:
        return JsonResponse({'Message':'request should be post'})
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /likepost/12
```

even though I have used csrf_exempt, can anyone help me?

Comment: probably you send the request to the wrong URL

Comment: it is going to the correct URL. please check code.